# Axiomatic approach to money, securities and other instruments?

Tags: stocks, paper-money, securities

As I read about cash, stocks, bonds, derivatives, etc., I can't help but wonder *why* there are so many diverse financial products out there.  Any pointers to axiomatic treatment that explains fundamental reasons for these securities and their equivalence would be super useful!

For example, *money* is any thing that serves as a medium of exchange, a measure of value, and a storage of value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are there so many types of transportation mechanisms (cars, bikes, trains, planes)? Why doesn't everyone just drive a car? Obviously, they each have their benefits in certain situations, and meet different needs.

Bonds are a way for companies to raise money to grow (or survive) by borrowing it from people or companies that are willing to lend it. In return, those investors expect to get paid interest in return.

Stocks are a way for companies to raise money by selling part of the ownership of the company (the "equity") to investors.  Since there is no guarantee of return, there is greater risk, but potentially greater reward.

Some investors may like the relative safety of bonds, but would like returns that are slightly higher, without taking the full risk of stocks. So *hybrid* instruments like convertible bonds, preferred stock, and other instruments were developed to bridge the gap and meet specific investor needs.

For commodities, futures, options, and other derivatives were created because consumers and producers of commodities needed a way to buy and sell their commodities without all the risk of price spikes, counterparties not being willing to pay, etc. *Futures* allow two counterparties to enter in a contract to buy or sell a commodity at a specific point in the future at an agreed-upon price. So a corn farmer in Iowa can set a price to sell his harvest before planting, and not have to worry about a price drop. *Options* also reduce risks but allow for some profit if prices move in the other direction. An airline can buy call options on gasoline, so that it can lock in a certain *maximum* price to pay, but if the price of gasoline drops, it can still buy at the lower price.

For similar reasons, there are financial instruments on interest rates, currency exchange rates, and more and more creative and complex derivatives. They are all designed to mitigate a specific risk, to take advantage of systematic flaws in financial markets, etc.

Certainly many of these are not used in their traditional sense anymore, but are used for speculation, or to meet investment risk/reward goals, but they do all exist for a reason.

Comment: "_So a corn farmer in Iowa can set a price to sell his harvest before planting, and not have to worry about a price drop_" or even just to have the money up-front to buy the seed to plant.

Comment: @TripeHound No, that's not how futures work. It's not a "pre-payment". You settle up when the futures settle. It just ensures that you get a specific price, so you don't have to worry about a price drop.

Comment: @D Stanley: But the futures contract could be used as security for a loan...

Answer (score 2):

In general, investments can be divided into fixed-income and equities and each has its own safety, return, as well as pros and cons.

Equities are stocks that trade on exchanges.   Equities have higher risk but offer  a potentially higher return on your money.   They may be pooled in mutual funds or ETFs which diversifies the assets and spreads the risk across a number of stocks.  Equity investments symbolize interest of ownership in a corporation.

Fixed-income includes corporate or government bonds and may also be pooled in bond ETFs or mutual funds. Bonds are solely a financial interest-earning investment.  CDs and savings accounts are also considered to be fixed-income investments.

The main advantage to of fixed income is certainty.  You'll know exactly how much money you'll have at the end of the investment period.

Preferred stocks are a hybrid of both but lean much more toward the fixed income side.

Your allocation in these categories should be based on your risk  tolerance.

Derivatives are a separate entity unto themselves.  They are more complex and require a higher level of financial literacy to employ properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Though the question is framed naively, I was hoping for a more deeper/philosophical treatment (e.g., the fact that fixed-income securities have the pro of "certainty" at face value; futures also have this property but for other uses, etc.) 
 Maybe this isn't the right community to ask the question?

Comment: Naively framed isn't the problem.  You asked a non specific question about a vast array of financial vehicles and their uses.  Many 1,000s of books have been written  about every aspect of them.  If you want a deeper/philosophical treatment of the topic, you're going to have to pose deeper/philosophical questions.

Answer (score 0):

Financial instruments tend to exist if they meet a need for hedging/speculation on uncertain, economically significant events/outcomes. The profusion of instruments can be viewed as approaching the ideal of a [complete market](https://files.stlouisfed.org/research/publications/review/91/03/Markets_Mar_Apr1991.pdf), in which bets can be placed on every possible outcome that might matter to anyone, thereby theoretically maximizing the efficiency of risk allocations.